# Find matrix and inverse of linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathcal{A}:\mathcal{P_3}\rightarrow {M_{2,2}}$ is a linear operator defined as $\mathcal{A}(a+bx+cx^2+dx^3)=$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a+c+2d & 2a-3b+c+4d \\
        b+2c-d & -a+4b+c-3d \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

Find matrix of $\mathcal{A}$ in standard basis and inverse of $\mathcal{A}$ (if exists).

Could someone give a hint how to find matrix of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{A}^{-1}$?

Comment: Do you remember how matrix coefficients were defined?

Comment: @s.harp I don't understand your question.

Comment: Do you know what a matrix is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Write the transformation in vector notation using the standard basis for $P_3$ :
$$
\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}
$$
and $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} \quad\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix} \quad\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix} \quad
\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
$$
so that it is:
$$A \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}a+c+2d\\2a-3b+c+4d\\b+2c-d\\-a+4b+c-3d\end{bmatrix} $$
and you can see immediately that $T$ is represented by the matrix: 
$$
T=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1&2\\2&-3&1&4\\0&1&2&-1\\-1&4&1&-3\end{bmatrix} $$

Now you can find $A^{-1}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can think of your transformation as a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $M_{2,2}$. What do you need to multiply $(a,b,c,d)$ by to get the result?